# TzitTzit tangles

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tying-knots-kosheir

We know the knots are the most important part of the TzitTzit.  No matter which method you use to tie them:
How tangled is too tangled for the strings of the TzitTzit?
What is the definition of tangled vs knotted?

Comment: morah hochman, could you clarify your question?  What do you mean by "the knots are the most important part"?  What source are you using?  When you want to know about tangled vs knotted, could you explain the precise case that you are interested in comparing?

Answer (score 2):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (which brings from many different sources) gives very exact details on how to tie the knots for tzitzis. Yes, the minimum is one knot (and one *chulya*), but ideally there is a certain specific arrangement.

The idea of tzitzis not being tangled is (to my understanding) primarily *after* the section of knots (which should be 1/3 of the entire length). So once all the knots that are necessary have been tied, the strings should hang freely, and not be tangled or knotted.

The Shulchan Aruch HaRav says, "the word tzitis can only refer to separated strings. Therefore it is important to separate the strings before making the Bracha".

How tangled is too tangled? To my understanding, any entanglement that prevents each individual string from hanging freely, i.e. by itself. So if two or more strings are tangled in a way that they're stuck together, or one or more strings are knotted beyond the "knot section", then that's too tangled.

Comment: Is the last paragraph also based on the Kitzur SA?

Comment: No. Most of this answer is _my understanding_ of the KSA. It does say that before donning the tallis, one must separate the strings (obviously referring to the free-hanging part) to make sure they are not tangled with one another. It consistently refers to the end of the tzitzis as "hanging strings", both words in the plural. To me, that means that each should be hanging independently of the others.